# Embedded ratings widget or addon for putting ratings/reviews on our web site?

Tags: web-applications, embed, widgets

I need to integrate a product rating and review feature into my company's product pages.

Rather than build one from scratch, I am exploring the options available for third party products, such as [powerreviews.com](http://www.powerreviews.com). *(Our site users will provide all of the ratings and reviews. We do not need to buy reviews).*

Ideally, I am looking for something like [Disqus](http://www.disqus.com) where I simply accepted the default values in the administrator and added a couple of lines in my site and voila, I had an awesome comments section to each page of my web site.

What are the options to add product ratings and reviews to our site?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many options so far as I can see. I don't have any direct experience with anything beyond [wordpress plugins that add similar functionality](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=product%20reviews).

- [Pluck Reviews](http://www.pluck.com/products/reviews.html)
- [Rating System](http://www.rating-system.com/)

Comment: These are exactly what I was looking for. I will investigate them. I will leave this question open in hopes that someone will come up with a few more ideas too.

Comment: Glad to be of help, it may be worth looking through the companies that offer the wordpress plugins as some of the plugins are really made as advertising for a service company.